# Infinite batch script is stopped after some time

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, batch-processing

I created a batch script file to detect the occurance of a certain event. Then I ran that batch file as a background process using the following code, saved in a .vbs file:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

I dont know why after 1 - 2 hours the process of that job will disappear, or I don't know why that job is not running in continuously without any interruption, as its designed and planned to do.

Can any one tell me why? And how to solve this issue? I mean how to make my hidden batch file to run for unlimited period of time?

This is the batch file

```
@ECHO OFF
set count=0
:LOOP
REM To Check the battery status, providing that 1 is discharging
REM and 2 is connected to the AC
for /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (
    'WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus /format:textvaluelist.xsl'
) do @if "BatteryStatus"=="%%a" call :DoStaff "%%b"
:DoStaff
IF %~1 EQU 2 (
    if %count% NEQ 0 (
        set count=0
        netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=enabled
        netsh wlan connect name=GUEST
        REM will delay execution of the next command by 10 seconds
        TIMEOUT /T 10
    )
) 
IF %~1 NEQ 2 (
    set /a count=%count%+1
    if %count% EQU 1 (
        REM Disable the wireless interface
        netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=disabled
    )
)
TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK > nul
GOTO :LOOP
```

Comment: Maybe the continuous recursion fills up your stack memory? Just guessing here. How are you triggering the VBS file? Do they run each other, or do you use windows task scheduler?

Comment: i used windows task schedular for running .vbs file

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were rerunning the batch file over and over again. This is not the case then, you just run it once, right?

Comment: The VBScript you posted starts your batch script and terminates. It has nothing to do with whatever happens afterwards. Without seeing your batch file there isn't much we could help you with except some general debugging guidelines. First step is always to check task history and eventlog for issues. Also, collect all output from the script in a logfile: `CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "cmd /c """ & WScript.Arguments(0) & """ >""%TEMP%\your.log"" 2>&1", 0, False`. And why are you using VBScript to launch the batch file instead of running it directly from the task?

Comment: Ansgar : because i need the batch file to be hidden process i dont want to see the command prompt, this is first thing. second. since the .vbs starts my batch script and terminates, why after awhile the batch file process will terminate as well, i mean it will not run longer than 2- 3 hours, where i need to run it without stop, how to acheive that ?

Comment: vacip , i used to run the batch file but i dont like that it will show the black screen , so i ran that batch file using .vbs file, but the problem here i dont know why the batch file process is stopped after awhile where i need it to be un stoppable task !!

Comment: for our use purpose it will not be a good suggestion to re run the task using task schedular every 1 hour.. i need the process to be on going until i'll stop it !

Comment: It's the batch file that's failing, not the .vbs script.  You would need to post the batch file for us to see what's wrong with it.  Although: have you checked the scheduler settings?  I think the scheduler can be configured to stop the job if it runs too long.

Comment: Scheduled tasks run hidden if configured correctly (your account needs the "log on as batch job" privilege for this). As for the second part of your comment: please re-read what I wrote. All of it.

Comment: DEAR HARRY, I NEED IT TO RUN FOR UN STOPPABLE PERIOD, CONTINUASLY!

Comment: i'll post the batch file

Comment: @L22222, Does your batch file launched manually work continuously, or breaks after some time?

Comment: i didnt check that, but i will check it today .. actually its good that you point that , thanks Omega !

Comment: Yes, a continuously running batch script could be made to work. But Ansgar's suggestion (and answer) of a short running batch script that is automatically launched every minute by the task scheduler is an excellent idea.

Answer (score 4):

```
@ECHO OFF
set count=0
:LOOP
REM To Check the battery status, providing that 1 is discharging and 2 is connected to the AC   
for /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus /format:textvaluelist.xsl') do @if "BatteryStatus"=="%%a" call :DoStaff "%%b"

:: You are CALLing the following routine. 
:: IF the routine was to terminate then batch would return to here on termination.
:: BUT the routine doesn't terminate - it loops back to LOOP
:: (Which invokes another CALL, loop back to LOOP ) ad infinitum
:: eventually, you run out of stack space and the batch terminates.

:: Fix : Loop back here

GOTO LOOP

:DoStaff
IF %~1 EQU 2 (
    if %count% NEQ 0 (
    set count=0
    netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=enabled
    netsh wlan connect name=EPFL-GUEST
    REM will delay execution of the next command by 10 seconds
    TIMEOUT /T 10
)
) 
IF %~1 NEQ 2 (
    set /a count=%count%+1
        if %count% EQU 1 (
        REM Disable the wireless interface
        netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=disabled
)
)
TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK > nul

:: Here you need to terminate the subroutine.
:: You could simply make thsi end-of-file,
:: But this following line forces the issue.
:: note that the colon before EOF is mandatory.
:: batch understands "GOTO :EOF" to mean, very specifically,
:: Go To End of physical file

GOTO :EOF

:: This following gotoline is not needed. it should be deleted.
GOTO :LOOP
```

Each time you `CALL` the subroutine, you add 1 more return address to the stack. Since you never terminate the subroutine (by reaching end-of-file or an `EXIT` statement) then you eventually run out of stack space.

Comment: yes. Additionally, delayed expansion may be needed with `%count%` (in the `NEQ` branch). Depends, if you want to disconnect on the first or the second notice of power-loss

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. i understand the flow, but what if my situation request the loops to keep looping without any stop even if the stack is full. i mean is there is a way to identify before stack becoming full to re initiate the operation again ?

Comment: By removing the last Go to loop statement, i am termenating this batch script once an event is detected!!! which is not the case that my batch is designed my batch for. The electricity might cut then might return back then cut then return back. i need the batch file to be continuasly runing whether any of the condition is met or not !!

Comment: Not the case. It is the *subroutine* `:Dostaff` that is terminated. Since that subroutine is `CALL`ed in the `for` loop, execution will return to the new `goto loop` inserted above the label `dostaff` and continue looping. Note Stephan's comment - within the block (sequence of statements enclosed in parentheses) `count` will be replaced by its value when the *entire* block is encountered, not the changed value caused by the increment on the previous line. See many SO articles on `delayedexpansion` for why.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your script correctly you want to switch off your wireless adapter if the computer is on battery, and switch it back on when power returns. My recommendation would be to reduce the code in your batch script to switching the adapter on/off:

```
@echo off

set "interface=Wi-Fi"
set "network=EPFL-GUEST"

REM get battery state (1 => discharging, 2 => connected to AC)
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (
    'wmic Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus /format:textvaluelist.xsl'
) do if "BatteryStatus"=="%%a" set "BatteryState=%%b"

REM get wireless interface state
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (
  'netsh interface show interface "%interface%" ^| find /i "administrative state"'
) do set "InterfaceState=%%~a"

if %BatteryState% equ 2 (
    if /i "%InterfaceState%"=="disabled" (
        netsh interface set interface name="%interface%" admin=enabled
        netsh wlan connect name="%network%"
    )
) else if /i "%InterfaceState%"=="enabled" (
    netsh interface set interface name="%interface%" admin=disabled
)
```

and change the scheduled task to run the batch script (without the VBScript launcher) at startup, repeating every minute indefinitely.

[image: Scheduled Task trigger: Begin at startup, repeat every minute indefinitely.]

The task should also be configured to run whether the user is logged on or not (your account needs the ["log on as batch job" privilege](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277311.aspx) for this).

[image: Scheduled Task setting: Run whether user is logged on or not, don't store the password.]

Comment: Appreciated !! but imagine that i need each time to notify me by sms that the electricity is off, i.e. whenever it will switch off the wireless adapter, to shoot me an email about that !! like that every minute i would expect it to send me an email whenever there is electricity failure, where i need only to have it once at that situation, and once when the adapter is switch on back again ! so your way is not suitable for my case scenario!

Comment: @L22222 If you take a closer look at the script, you may notice that `netsh` depends on 2 conditions: on battery *and* wireless on => switch off, on AC *and* wireless off => switch on. The script doesn't take an action for the situations "on battery and wireless off" or "on AC and wirless on".

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [Ansgar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34577251/1012053). But it is possible to get your original design to work.

[Magoo identified why your script eventually fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34576644/1012053), but there is an additional flaw in your logic.

You initialize `count` to 0, which means you assume that upon startup, both the AC is connected, and WiFi is enabled.

But if AC is connected and WiFi happens to be disabled, then your code never enables WiFi.

Here is one way to fix the problem.

```
@echo off

:: Force the initial iteration to always enable or disable WiFi
set "priorState=0"

:LOOP
for /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (
  'WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus /format:textvaluelist.xsl'
) do if "%%a"=="BatteryStatus" call :DoStuff "%%b"
goto :LOOP

:DoStuff
if %~1 neq %priorState% (
    if %~1 equ 2 (
        %= Connected to AC, so enable WiFi =%
        netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=enabled
        netsh wlan connect name=EPFL-GUEST
    ) else (
        %= Discharging battery, so disable WiFi =%
        netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=disabled
    )
    set "priorState=%~1"
)
timeout /t 60 /nobreak > nul
exit /b
```

It is possible to put everything in one infinite FOR /L loop so that no CALL and no GOTO are required. However, delayed expansion must be used so the loop can see the changing priorState value.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Force the initial iteration to always enable or disable WiFi
set "priorState=0"

:: Infinite loop
for /l %%N in () do (
  for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%A in (
    'wmic path Win32_Battery get BatteryStatus /format:textvaluelist.xsl'
  ) do if "%%A"=="BatteryStatus" if "%%B" neq "!priorState!" (
    %= Battery state has changed =%
    if %%B equ 2 (
      %= Connected to AC, so enable WiFi =%
      netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=enabled
      netsh wlan connect name=EPFL-GUEST
    ) else (
      %= Discharging battery, so disable WiFi =%
      netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=disabled
    )
    set "priorState=%~1"
  )
  timeout /t 60 /nobreak > nul
)
```

Comment: You and Magoo are ending this script whenever each of the condition is me, i.e. AC or battery is detected , execute the code , then terminate the script. which is not my case scenario !! the AC might be detected now , but after awhile the laptop might run by its battery, then after awhile the AC might return back. when there is no continuance check for these states , how to know the occurred change in laptop power !!

Comment: @L22222 - Read some documentation, and test the code we have given you. Heck, my last set of code doesn't even have EXIT /B, so why do you think it would terminate? The EXIT /B at the end of my first code ends the subroutine so that it returns to the main loop. It does not terminate the script. The main loop is in an infinite GOTO loop. But if you put forth a little effort, you could have discovered that for yourself.